# project file not found during git cloning repository in AppCode

Tags: github, appcode

i want to clone the repository from github to the JetBrains IDE AppCode and edit it

I did everything as [it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyiBnyPPnG4).  but the folders are not displayed

they are in the computer, but not in the appcode

I have little reputation for posting images so here are the links

[here](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5wkm/2i2kq8cYg).
[and here](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3Z8n/5vKquELbW).

Comment: Your links do not directly lead to the images, instead I get a page in Russian, which I am unable to navigate, can you post them somewhere else? Also, when you say "they are in the computer, but not in the appcode" do you mean that when you view the folder in Explorer/Finder/whatever all the files/folders are there but AppCode does not show them?

Comment: @Bob: Yes that's right, they are on the computer, but they are not in the project. The links corrected

Comment: @Bob: look please photo

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a .xcodeproj/.xcworkspace file in your project folder. .xcodeproj/.xcworkspace represent the project structure, and without it AppCode cannot open the project (same as Xcode). To work with your project in AppCode, you need to create it using the Project Wizard in AppCode or in Xcode first.